# would it be possible to track all/most changes in magentos admin?

Tags: php, magento

if I wanted to track changes that admin users perform, what would be the easiest way?

I wouldn't need to know exactly what they changed...just that they updated a category page, or modified a configuration setting, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is available by default in Magento's Enterprise Edition, but I am assuming that you want it in Community Edition?

Branko at Inchoo has written a nice [blog post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/logging-user-customer-actions-in-magento/) on this, it seems that the packaged version is no longer available, but his code hints should be enough to get it running.  If not, post another question here and we should be able to assist.

Comment: awesome!  great insight!!! I didn't know about this.  You are correct that I was looking into the community edition! Thanks!!